# Javascript variable equals to variable true

Tags: javascript, variables, equals

OK, I can't really describe it word by word so I will use an example:

```
function f1() {
  document.write(vavariable)
};

function f2(){
  if(variablefot)
    document.body.style.color='red';
};

variablefot = false;
variablefotok = variablefot = true;
variable1 = 'text1' +variablefotok;

variable2 = 'text2';

vavariable = variable1
```

NOW when I use `<script>f1();f2();</script>` and vavariable = variable1
I should get red text1
But I am getting red text1 + text 'true'

When I use vavariable2 I want to get text2 with no body color red
But I am still getting RED text2

I was trying to do it with function, but it also doesn't work.

Please, help me to make it working. I've lost few hours already trying to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen?

Comment: I want to get text1 and body color red when I use vavariable=variable1. And when I use vavariable=variable2 I want to get text2 with no red body color.

Comment: At the bottom of the first code block, before you call `f1` and `f2`, what do you think that is in the variables?

Comment: I thought I wrote it clear, but now I am realized I am not, so sorry and now I will try to make it really cear. I need to make function f2 enabled when variable1 is being used (on vavariable). If I use variable2 (on vavariable) the f2 function should be disabled.
Also I didn't mentioned that body color is just for example. What I am going to use instead of body color is other document.write.

Comment: Thank you for you answers guys, I found my answer by myself and it's quite obvious...

All I needed is to change code if like that:


    if(vavariable == variable1)

And that's it. This works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Variablefotok is equal to true, so that is why that is true is being written.

To change the body color, just use the f2 function except change the color back to the default, black. Essentially, you can write the text to the document and change color depending on the variable each time, or you could just write HTML code to the document like `<span style="color:red">text</span>` or `<span style="color:black">text</span>`. You could also use classes for those instead of inline CSS declarations. This would work for that case.

```
function write(){
    document.write(text);
    document.body.style.color = color;
}

variable1 = 'text1';
variable2 = 'text2';
```

With that code, you can just execute the following functions. You could also use it as much as you want like shown, if you have all the text stored in variables.

```
write(variable1, 'red');
write(variable2, 'black');
write(variable3, 'green');
write(variable4, 'blue');
write(variable5, 'brown');
write(variable6, 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with:

```
variablefotok = variablefot=true;
```

will first assign true to variablefot, and then to variablefotok. Both will thus be true.

```
variable1 = 'text1' +variablefotok;
```

Since variablefotok is `true`, variable1 will now be `'text1true'`. And thus variable will eventually be `'text1true'`.

```
function f2(){
    if(variablefot) 
        document.body.style.color='red';
};
```

Will (when called) change body's color to red if variablefot = true. Since this one is true, it will be always change body's color to red, no matter the value of variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's *really* unclear what you are trying to do, but I may be able to help anyway.

Here's what you have, more or less: http://jsfiddle.net/ySqGg/

> I should get red text1 But I am getting red text1 + text 'true'

This happens because you are "adding" `true` to a string.

```
variablefotok = variablefot=true;
// variablefotok and variablefofot are now both set to true

variable1 = 'text1' +variablefotok;
// same as: variable1 = 'text1' + true;
// `true` is converted into a string so it can be combined with a string
// variable1 is now `text1true`
```

So why does that happen? Well lets look one line earlier:

```
variablefot = false;
variablefotok = variablefot = true;
```

This can be clarified as follows:

```
variablefot = false;
variablefotok = (variablefot = true);
```

So first you set `variablefot` to `false`.  Then on the next line you set it to `true`. Assignment statements return the assigned value, and so you set `variablefotok` to true as well.

Then later `f2` runs, and `variablefot` is now true, and you get red.

Did you mean to do a comparison instead?

```
variablefotok = (variablefot == true);
```

With this change, the text does *not* turn red, because `variablefot` remains `false`. http://jsfiddle.net/ySqGg/1/

But you rarely have to compare anything to `true`.  You can simply use the variable, since it's `true` or `false`.

```
variablefotok = variablefot;
```

Which also does not turn anything red. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ySqGg/2/

---

This is confusing to answer because you are setting many variables, but only *using* one for anything usefult (`variablefot` in `f2`).  If I were you I'd think about what variables you have and make sure you really need every one, then delete the others.